# Consecutive integers divisible by consecutive small numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression, divisors-multiples

Given $n$, what is the largest set of consecutive integers in $[n,2n]$ can we have so that each integer is divisible by a distinct element from $[\log n,2\log n]$ (no partiular order)? So apriori I am asking if we can achieve the maximum of $\log n$ consecutive integers.

Comment: @BenBarber No, he wants as many as possible of these multiples to constitute an interval $I\subset[n,2n]$.

Comment: @Wolfgang Thank you, that was a particularly silly misreading of the question.  I'll delete it to reduce clutter.